# MySql Realtime Database

Tags: mysql

I want to use mysql to change a columns data continuous .(i.e : every one or two seconds , by minumum 50 or 100 users)

in example

```
realtime_db:
id|name|surname|point(this will update in every 1,2 seconds)
0 |user0|surname0|50
1 |user1|surname1|19
2 |user2|surname2|234
3 |user3|surname3|21
4 |user4|surname4|45
```

is mysql suitable for changing a columns data continuous ?

Comment: What concerns about suitability are you having?

Comment: maybe most of users invokes adding point method to mysql and mysql gets lag and errors occur.. i'm currently using mysql to put and read tables.i don't know how this effects to mysql.

Comment: If MySQL couldn't deal with such a scenario, no one would use it. Any good relational database handles that, that's why they're made for (not only MySQL, but Postgres, MSSQL etc)

Answer (score -1):

Mysql with InnoDb has good performance for concurrent updates. 
The bottleneck could be:

- Max mysql client connections: Default is 151
  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)
- The backend that run the updates. If it's a web interface you need to
  put attention to the webserver and max concurrent connections. In Apache, maxclients (default 256) and other related variables http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#maxclients)